# lexer terminology: token vs. token rule vs. token type

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction, lexer

I'm trying to create a lexer just for sake of learning, and I'm having a hard time to understand exactly what is token vs. token rule vs token type. If I understand correctly:

- *token*: these are instances of lexemes that are returned to a parser when requested. They can have a *value* (a.k.a lexeme), *type* (e.g. `KEYWORD_IF`), *literal* and *position*.
- *token type*: an enumeration of the special keywords (e.g. `RIGHT_PARENTHESIS`)
- *token rule*: same as above

To better get my head around it, I'm creating a simple lexer using TypeScript. The user will be able to define the rules as follow:

```js
import { lexer } from '..'

lexer.rules
  .add('<IDENTIFIER>', /<regex>/)
  .add('<IDENTIFIER>', /<regex>/)
```

and the signature of `add`:

```js
export function add(id: string, regexp: RegExp) {
  // code here
}
```

What I don't fully understand is if the terminology and names are correct. Should I use rules or tokens, e.g:

```
lexer.tokens
  .add('<IDENTIFIER>', /<regex>/)
  .add('<IDENTIFIER>', /<regex>/)
```

or maybe `tokenTypes`:

```js
lexer.tokenTypes
  .add('<IDENTIFIER>', /<regex>/)
  .add('<IDENTIFIER>', /<regex>/)
```

Also, should I call the left-side identifier or maybe name?

Comment: The rule is the part that recognizes the type. In your case it is the regular expression that identifies the token type.

Comment: Personally I would call it `tokenTypes` even though it contains pairs of (token type, rule), just because "token type" is more readily understandable by someone who hasn't read a textbook about parsers. Or call it `tokenRegexes` or something like that.